# Smooth lerp towards a moving target

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics

I stumbled upon this function that lerp towards a moving target with exponential correction which works really well. The original author mentioned integrating the target position. Can anyone explain how this works in mathematical terms? How would I implement this for Quaternion?

```
Vector3 SuperSmoothLerp(Vector3 x0, Vector3 y0, Vector3 yt, float t, float k)
{
    Vector3 f = x0 - y0 + (yt - y0) / (k * t);
    return yt - (yt - y0) / (k*t) + f * Mathf.Exp(-k*t);
}
```

> x0 is the follower's old position, y0 is the target's old position, yt is the target's new position, t is the elapsed time, and k is the lerp rate, as in (1 - Mathf.Exp(-k * Time.deltaTime)) before. You used 20 for that. The return value is the follower's new position. So you call it much like Vector3.Lerp, except you pass the target's old and new positions, rather than just its new position.

> The maths assumes that the target is moving with constant velocity over the time slice, so if the target is changing velocity rapidly as well it's still going to jitter a bit. But in any case it should be a lot more smooth than plain Lerp was, and other than being smooth, it has exactly the same behaviour (e.g. response to different k values, following distance, etc).

Original post (by George Foot):
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-smooth-damp-towards-a-moving-target-without-causing-jitter-in-the-movement.130920/

Comment: You've got a mathematical function along with a description of what the function does and of each of the variables in the function. What more explanation do you need to understand the function "in mathematical terms"? Why would you need to implement this for Quaternions?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `SuperSmoothLerp()` performs many calculations repeatedly and can be optimized for better performance. You may find it easier to understand if you rename the variables with meaningful names (e.g. followerOld, targetOld, targetNew, etc

Comment: @Kevin Shouldn't common subexpression elimination be handled by the compiler?

Comment: The original author labelled this solution "Write the lerp as a differential equation and solve it properly." @michael Are you asking how you'd write the quaternion lerp as a differential equation and how to solve it? It would also help to describe how you want to use the quaternion lerp.

Comment: @DMGregory Is it? I didn't know that. Personally, I always replace repeated subexpressions with variables anyway for legibility and easier editing.